# in oracle SQL developer How do I display list of all tables from current user/schema

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I m working in oracle SQL developer database where I want to display list of all tables from current user/schema

Answer (score 1):

You see the list of tables as owned by the current schema user in the Tree view of the connection under "tables". If you login as sys, then you see sys owned (of course).

If you want to see the schema of a different user, you need to have select permissions on the tables (and maybe some more in SQL Developer). Then you can see the tables of the other schema under `<Connection>/Other Users/<User>/Tables/*`.

If you don't see tables there, then you need to check for Synonyms, global synonyms or views. Finally if none of them are showing the expected tables (and you are aure you logged into the correct instance and CDB) then there might be a different active default schema for your user active after logon (typical case of a logon trigger). In this case the statement from before applies: look under the user who owns them.

SQL Developer internally used the `ALL_*` and `USER_` system views. For example your tables owned by you: `select TABLE_NAME from user_tables`. More complete description of that is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25859169/in-oracle-sql-developer-how-do-i-display-list-of-all-tables-from-current-user-sc/25859205).

Comment: thanks eckes. I was tried to see those tables by using  syntax.

Comment: @Prajnyique Ah OK, if you want to know the SQL statement, you should not ask for the Tool. I have added the statement and a link to an existing answer. Please be so kind and accept the answer if it helps.